# System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that is spitting out tonnes of exceptions to the log and they're all the same

```
2023-07-06|05:09:34.6824|142|Error|System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)|Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.|HttpApplication.RecordError => HttpApplication.RaiseOnError => MvcApplication.Application_Error
```

I'm trying to locate where the cause of this is. But cannot seem to locate the entry point from the log (I'm using NLOG to handle the logs and they're being written to file on the disk)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I have looked at handler attributes and can only see this which does not appear to change the status

```
    public class HandleAntiForgeryError : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var exception = filterContext.Exception as HttpAntiForgeryException;
            if (exception == null) return;

            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
            routeValues["controller"] = "Account";
            routeValues["action"] = "Login";

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You likely have some kind of global error handler that is rewriting the headers somehow (perhaps trying to set the status?). Based only on the line with `HandleErrorAttribute.OnException` you might also look for an action decorated with `[HandleError]`...

Comment: Based on error message, you are setting response code after sending your response. I would start investigating from controller and middlewares.

Comment: Thanks, @HereticMonkey and Orifjon, I'll try that and see how it goes

Comment: Looks like you are getting an error at the server and returning the response then trying to send an error status after the response was already set.  Start by finding root cause of the error.